# task process doesn't work xamarin.android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, process, task

i have this task process that should control text of my edittext and when the lenght is 21 it should run a method.
It seems that the process runs once
this is the code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                 if (macAddress.Text.Length == 21)
                {
                     address = Regex.Replace(macAddress.Text, "[^0-9.]", "");
                 }

                 btSocket = b.AndroidBtConnection(address, MY_UUID);
                 if (btSocket == null)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("connessione nulla");
                     macAddress.Text = "";
                 }
             });
```

Comment: You Cant access UI elements in another thread different from UI thread.

Comment: What is the question? You need to ensure you use `RunOnUiThread` to update your respective UI accordingly.

Comment: could you make an example? @JonDouglas

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/writing_responsive_applications/